# Weird errors with \textbf in math mode

Tags: math-mode

```
Atomic nuclei are associated with an intrinsic angular momentum called the spin angular momentum $\textbf{J}$. A dimensionless spin angular momentum $\textbf{I}$ is defined as $\textbf{I} = \textbf{J}/\hbar$. The magnitude and direction of $\textbf{I}$ are quantized in the sense that the magnitude of the vector is 
\begin{equation}\label{nmr1}
|\textbf{I}| = \sqrt{I(I + 1)}
\end{equation}
Here $I = 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \frac{3}{2},...$. If $\textbf{I} \neq 0$, the nucleus has a magnetic dipole moment $\textbf{\mu} = \gamma\hbar\textbf{I}$. The quantity $\gamma$ is gyromagnetic ratio, which is specific for each nucleus.

The magnetic moment in an external magnetic field experiences a torque $\textbf{N} = \textbf{\mu}\times\textbf{B_0}$ which tends to align the magnetic moment with the external field because it is energetically favorable for the magnetic moment to be in that orientation. The equation of motion for the magnetic moment in an external magnetic field is
\begin{equation}\label{nmr2}
\frac{d\textbf{\mu}}{dt} = -\gamma\textbf{B_0}\times\textbf{\mu}
\end{equation}
Equation \ref{nmr2} describes a vector $\textbf{\mu}$ precessing about the direction of $B_0$ with angular frequency $\omega = -\gamma B_0$. This motion is known as the Larmor precession. The Larmor frequency can be written as 
\begin{equation}\label{nmr3}
\nu = \frac{\omega}{2\pi} = -\frac{\gamma}{2\pi}B_0
\end{equation}
```

I am writing the above text in overleaf. I get this error:

```
<inserted text> 
                $
l.545 ...as a magnetic dipole moment $\textbf{\mu}
                                                   = \gamma\hbar\textbf{I}$....
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\textdef@ ...th {#1}\let \f@size #2\selectfont #3}
                                                  }
l.545 ...as a magnetic dipole moment $\textbf{\mu}
                                                   = \gamma\hbar\textbf{I}$....
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

And the other error is:

```
\textdef@ ...h {#1}\let \f@size #2\selectfont #3}}
                                                  
l.545 ...as a magnetic dipole moment $\textbf{\mu}
                                                   = \gamma\hbar\textbf{I}$....
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\text@ ...style \ssf@size {\firstchoice@false #1}}
                                                  \check@mathfonts }
l.545 ...as a magnetic dipole moment $\textbf{\mu}
                                                   = \gamma\hbar\textbf{I}$....
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

I did not find any typos from the text. What causes these errors?

Comment: `\textbf` makes _text_ not math so `\textbf{B_0}`  or `\textbf{\mu}` is an error, use `\mathbf` but to make `\mu` bold you would need `\bm` from `bm` package

Comment: overleaf is not involved here it is just hosting a stadard tex installation, and you would get the same error anywhere

Comment: Note that `\textbf` is not the way to get bold letters in math; use `\mathbf` when in math mode for Latin letters and `\bm` for Greek ones. Usually it's `\mathbf{B}_{0}` because the digit 0 should generally not be bold (unless it must for some reason).

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- Replace all instances of `\textbf{I}` and `\textbf{J}` with `\mathbf{I}` and `\mathbf{J}`, respectively.
- Load the `bm` package and replace all instances of `\textbf{\mu}` with `\bm{\mu}`.
- Replace all instances of `textbf{B_0}` with `\mathbf{B}_0`, i.e., do *not* bold-face the `0` subscript.
- Be sure to load the `amsmath` package and replace `Equation \ref{nmr2}` with `Equation~\eqref{nmr2}`.
- If you want bold-math to be rendered in italic (or slanted) rather than in upright letters, just replace all instances of `\mathbf` with `\bm`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}

Atomic nuclei are associated with an intrinsic angular momentum 
called the spin angular momentum~$\mathbf{J}$. A dimensionless 
spin angular momentum~$\mathbf{I}$ is defined as 
$\mathbf{I} = \mathbf{J}/\hbar$. The magnitude and direction 
of~$\mathbf{I}$ are quantized in the sense that the magnitude 
of the vector is
\begin{equation}\label{nmr1}
\lvert\mathbf{I}\rvert = \sqrt{I(I + 1)}\,.
\end{equation}
Here $I = 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5,\dotsc$ If $\mathbf{I}\ne 0$, 
the nucleus has a magnetic dipole moment $\bm{\mu} = 
\gamma\hbar\mathbf{I}$. The quantity $\gamma$ is the 
gyromagnetic ratio, which is specific for each nucleus.

The magnetic moment in an external magnetic field experiences 
a torque $\mathbf{N} = \bm{\mu}\times\mathbf{B}_0$ which tends 
to align the magnetic moment with the external field because 
it is energetically favorable for the magnetic moment to be 
in that orientation. The equation of motion for the magnetic 
moment in an external magnetic field is
\begin{equation}\label{nmr2}
\frac{d\bm{\mu}}{dt} = -\gamma\mathbf{B}_0\times\bm{\mu}\,.
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{nmr2} describes a vector $\bm{\mu}$ precessing 
about the direction of~$\mathbf{B}_0$ with angular frequency 
$\omega = -\gamma \mathbf{B}_0$. This motion is known as the 
Larmor precession. The Larmor frequency can be written as
\begin{equation}\label{nmr3}
\nu = \frac{\omega}{2\pi} = -\frac{\gamma}{2\pi}\mathbf{B}_0\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico `|\textbf{I}| = \sqrt{I(I + 1)}` is correct. The `I` under the square root is the quantum number associated with the angular momentum operator `\mathbf{I}`. Although the more common way to write this would be as an eigenvalue equation `\mathbf{I}^2 \lvert I, m_I \rangle = I (I + 1) \lvert I, m_I \rangle`, cf. the first equation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_quantum_number

Comment: @HenriMenke - Thanks for this explanation. (I’m not a physicist…) Will fix soon.